# IntelliSense / Code Completion in vscode with module federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack-module-federation

We have a client web react application which consumes specific react components via module federation (remote and not via npm package). It all works well !
While coding in VSCode (or IntelliJ) we really like to have intelliSense which will automatically complete the props for this component (which we load via React.lazy() from a remote location url). What is the best option to achieve that ? we would like to avoid installing this component via npm.